# WeekNum VBA function doesn't output the value on specific computer

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016, week-number

I was looking for an answer however I failed.
I wrote following code that basically adds a new row to the table and adds a current week number in 1st cell of new row:

```
Set table = Workbooks("EMEA Day 2 Chasing Audit Master Report.xlsm").Worksheets("Team Stats").ListObjects.Item("TableLilla")
Set oLastrowStats = Workbooks("EMEA Day 2 Chasing Audit Master Report.xlsm").Worksheets("Team Stats").ListObjects("TableLilla").ListRows.Add
Worksheets("Team Stats").ListObjects("TableLilla").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange(oLastrowStats.Index, 1).Value = "W" & WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Now, vbMonday)
```

The weird part starts here: the code works as it should on 2 computers but it does not on third one. On the 3rd computer, new row is added but the 3rd code line doesn't insert a week number.
I'm pretty sure it is related with this particular notebook, however have no clue where to look for solution. I didn't notice any major differences in Excel Settings. I've also checked the Win10 regional and date set up and they are the same as on my notebook.

Do you have any clue how to sort this out?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you get an error? (If not, are you suppressing/handling errors?) Does it put *anything* in that cell at all?

Comment: Due to [MS Help](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.weeknum) problems can occur if dates are entered as text.

Comment: What happens if you use the VBA function for weeknumber instead.  The equivalent would be:  `DatePart("ww", Date, vbSunday, vbFirstJan1)`.  *Note that I use `Date` in place of `Now` as I am only interested in the date and not the time*.

Comment: @Rory I've commented out the whole error handling section so it not an issue (unfortunately). Nope, there are no any errors. New row is added correctly, only the week number cell remains empty. I heard smth that it might be related with different MS Office versions (32bit/64bit) however it's not as one of the notebooks the code works fine on is 32 and mine is 64 (the one where it doesn't work is 32). Thanks!

Comment: @RonRosenfeld sorry for late update. I had some time off. So tried your way and still doesn't work.

Comment: When it "doesn't work", does the entire cell remain blank? Or does the `W` get printed without a number?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a function that returns the ISO 8601 week number (and year):

```vb
' Constants.

    Public Const MaxWeekValue           As Integer = 53
    Public Const MinWeekValue           As Integer = 1
    Public Const MaxMonthValue          As Integer = 12
    Public Const MinMonthValue          As Integer = 1


' Returns the ISO 8601 week of a date.
' The related ISO year is returned by ref.
'
' 2016-01-06. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function Week( _
    ByVal Date1 As Date, _
    Optional ByRef IsoYear As Integer) _
    As Integer

    Dim Month       As Integer
    Dim Interval    As String
    Dim Result      As Integer
    
    Interval = "ww"
    
    Month = VBA.Month(Date1)
    ' Initially, set the ISO year to the calendar year.
    IsoYear = VBA.Year(Date1)
    
    Result = DatePart(Interval, Date1, vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays)
    If Result = MaxWeekValue Then
        If DatePart(Interval, DateAdd(Interval, 1, Date1), vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays) = MinWeekValue Then
            ' OK. The next week is the first week of the following year.
        Else
            ' This is really the first week of the next ISO year.
            ' Correct for DatePart bug.
            Result = MinWeekValue
        End If
    End If
        
    ' Adjust year where week number belongs to next or previous year.
    If Month = MinMonthValue Then
        If Result >= MaxWeekValue - 1 Then
            ' This is an early date of January belonging to the last week of the previous ISO year.
            IsoYear = IsoYear - 1
        End If
    ElseIf Month = MaxMonthValue Then
        If Result = MinWeekValue Then
            ' This is a late date of December belonging to the first week of the next ISO year.
            IsoYear = IsoYear + 1
        End If
    End If
    
    ' IsoYear is returned by reference.
    Week = Result
        
End Function
```

Like this:

```
Worksheets("Team Stats").ListObjects("TableLilla").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange(oLastrowStats.Index, 1).Value = "W" & Week(Date)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Will check it out!  Nevertheless I'm super curious what might be causing the issue I'm facing as all those 3 notebooks belong the the same company (same team) and are basically the same)